# Setting attributes for various elements in a CSS class

Tags: css, class, styles

Is this the only way to do it? I tried creating a div with the navbar class, so it would apply the class to the elements it contains, but it doesn't work. Is there a way I can avoid having to manually apply the class to every single element? Thanks.

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li class="navbar"><a href="index.html"  class="navbar">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbar"><a href="images.html"  class="navbar">Images</a></li>
</ul>
```

[adding a screenshot of my CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRGQg.png)

Thanks

Comment: You should use descendant or child selectors.  You don't need the class on every element.

Comment: Please avoid posting code as images, just copy and paste, then highlight and use `CTRL`+`K`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the simplest way to add class without doing it manually, you can use jquery otherwise, for the css part you can use only a class for the ul and no classes for the li, if you want a li to have a specific style use :nth-child(the number), :first-child or :last-child.

Ah and for your css, use:

.navbar li instead of using li.navbar because you don't need to specify the li you want to customize if you define which div you're customizing.

I hope I helped you,

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="images.html">Images</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**css**

Add the rules inside the skeleton below.

```
 .navbar {
 }

    .navbar > li {
    }

        .navbar > li > a {
        }

        .navbar > li > a:hover {
        }
```

**for fun**

I wanted to include this even though I answered it above. Don't think defining classes for child elements is bad practice. In fact, when you learn about OOCSS or BEM you will see its often encouraged. The advantage is that your markup can change and you will not have to make changes to your CSS.

```
.navbar {
}

    .navbar__item {
    }

        .navbar__link {
        }

        .navbar__link:hover {
        }
```